# Provide callback to Java function call from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to provide a callback to a class function written in Java by means of an anonymous abstract class instance, but from a groovy class. The code below illustrate my issue.

```
//Java Code
abstract class CallBackWrapper
{
    int someAttr, someOtherAttr;
    public abstract void execute();
    public int getAttr()
    {
        return someAttr;
    }
}

class Delegator 
{
    public void callExecute(CallBackWrapper w)
    {
        w.execute();
    }
}

//Groovy Code
class GroovyClass
{
    private void foo()
    {
        //Doesn't work
        Delegator d = new Delegator();
        d.callExecute(new CallBackWrapper() {
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
        });

        //Also doesn't work
        Delegator d = new Delegator();
        d.callExecute([execute:{println "HELLO from Groovy"}] as CallBackWrapper)
    }
}
```

The closest I got to getting it to work is by changing `CallBackWrapper` to an `interface` *AND* declaring it inside the Groovy class. However, I need an abstract class. My question is, how can I implement this callback behavior from "Groovy Land" so that the Java class understands? Currently I get Groovy runtime errors that are not very helpful in explaining the true nature of the issue.

Comment: What should work is `d.callExecute{println "HELLO from Groovy"} as CallBackWrapper)`. I didn't try it, so for now it's a comment :). Also, if it doesn't work, what's the error?

Comment: Yes, please provide the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your error, but I tried your code here and got the following error:

> $ javac *.java && groovy GroovyClass.groovy && rm *.class
>
> Caught: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class GroovyClass$1 cannot access its superclass CallBackWrapper
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class GroovyClass$1 cannot access its superclass CallBackWrapper

It happened due to Groovy's generated inner class being unable to access `CallBackWrapper`. I added the `public` modifier and it worked fine:

```
// Delegator.java
class Delegator {
    public void callExecute(CallBackWrapper w) {
        w.execute();
    }
}

// CallBackWrapper.java
public abstract class CallBackWrapper {
    int someAttr, someOtherAttr;
    public abstract void execute();
    public int getAttr()
    {
        return someAttr;
    }
}

// GroovyClass.groovy
class GroovyClass
{
    private void foo() {
        def d = new Delegator()
        d.callExecute { println "Hello from groovy" }
    }
    
    static main(args) {
        new GroovyClass().foo()
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity, I added `Delegator::me()` to Java code, invoked it from Groovy and it worked:

```
class Delegator {
    public void callExecute(CallBackWrapper w) {
        w.execute();
    }
    void me() {
        new CallBackWrapper() {
            public void execute() {
                System.out.println("Echo");
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Seems to me like a bug similar to [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4922). You could fill a jira.